# Can we use events (click - hover) on polyline Bing map?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, rest, bing-maps

I draw a grid area and would like to let the user choose to select a square on my map.

But i check the documentation and i am not sure if click or hover events exists ? I find it hard to believe that Microsoft has forgotten to add this feature.

***Here is the code i use for draw polyline in my ASP web app :***

```
for (var x = 5.955793; x < 10.491842; x += 0.01) 
{
    line = new Microsoft.Maps.Polyline([new Microsoft.Maps.Location(45.818064, x), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.808383, x)]);

    map.entities.push(line);
}
```

[image]

If somebody can help me, or show me some sample/documentation for add click event . Will be perfect

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here is a modified version of your code:

```
for (var x = 5.955793; x < 10.491842; x += 0.01) 
{
    line = new Microsoft.Maps.Polyline([new Microsoft.Maps.Location(45.818064, x), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.808383, x)]);
    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(line, "click", polylineClicked);
    map.entities.push(line);
}
```

You can than create a simple event handler function and get the line that was clicked:

```
function polylineClicked(e){
    var line = e.target;
}
```

If you want to add a hover event use the mouseover event instead of or in addition to the click event.